# Systemd service is spanning multiple process

Tags: systemd

So I've created my very first `systemd` service to run a python process. For that I built the following `test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Simple Test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle

ExecStart=/root/testApp/bin/python /root/testApp/run.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I placed this file at `/etc/systemd/system`and after enabling it its working fine. The App is running and I can `status`it. However `top` tells me it is running my testApp 3 times. Why?

Systemd status output also shows something like that:

```
service test status
● test.service - A Simple Test
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-06-28 21:48:54 CEST; 6min ago
 Main PID: 2051 (python)
   CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
           ├─2051 /root/testApp/bin/python /root/testApp/run.py
           └─2054 /root/testApp/bin/python /root/testApp/run.py
```

Why is this happening? Is it related to the `type` or any other setting? How should I fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using threads? If so, they show up as separate processes on Linux, so I suspect that'd be the cause.

Comment: @TollefFogHeen well I'm actually using them.